# merge contents of two files if string matches in each line

Tags: linux, unix, search, append

I have two files file1, file2 whose content look like below, each file has about 500 lines.

---

cat file1

```
user1 
job role :
user2
job role :
```

---

cat file2

```
user1     efg@xyz.com
user2     hij@xyz.com
user9  
user16    abc@xyz.com
```

---

I want a script to append the mail address of corresponding user from file2 below the line "job role" for every user in file 1.
The number of names and contacts is  both the files are different.

Comment: What have you already tried? This is not a place to ask people to do the programs for you

Comment: What should happen for users that don't exist in file1, for users that don't exist in file2, for users without email in file2 (see user9 in your sample)?

Comment: @jsbueno , i am new to scripting , tried googling a bit but of no use so came here looking for some help .

Comment: @choroba  
1) users not in file1 must be listed separately into a new file



2) users not existing in file2 and without a mail id  in file2  need a line something like " contact not found " in file1

Answer (score -1):

No attempt no help. I need at least 30 characters, hence the second sentence.

Comment: 30 characters what ?

Comment: To write a response to you that is not a comment. Show me what you tried and I would be happy to help. I just don't want to be writing code for people that haven't made an attempt to do anything. I am not saying that this is the case here it is just not documented in this question hence why other users are down-voting your question. If you can show me an attempt here I will show you how I would accomplish this.